# Is it possible to find out what application inserted the text into the clipboard?

Tags: winapi, clipboard

Is it possible to find out what application inserted the text into the clipboard?

My guess is no but I'm no windows API expert.

Comment: `GetClipboardOwner()` returns the **current** owner, not the **last known** owner.  Once an app closes the clipboard, it longer owns it. Also, an app must call `EmptyClipboard()` to gain ownership, and it is possible for the clipboard to have a NULL owner.

Comment: Once an app closes the clipboard, it **no longer** owns it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input. Seems like too much work. I just wanted to verify the data came from the correct application. However, I realized I could use a regex to verify the data came from the source application so that's easier.

Comment: If that is your application, register your own clipboard format.

Comment: nope, another application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for that purpose.  You would have to write a DLL that globally hooks the `SetClipboardData()` and `OleSetClipboard()` functions in every running process so it can keep track of clipboard assignments and convey that information back to your app when needed.